# Is biconjugate function $f^{**}$ the best approximation of $f$?

Tags: convex-analysis, approximation

Consider [biconjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate#Biconjugate) $f^{**}$ of given nonconvex function $f$.

It is well known that $f^{**}$ is the greatest convex minorant of $f$ such that $f \geq f^{**}$.

I wonder whether $f^{**}$ is also the best approximation of $f$, that is, $\hat{f} = f^{**}$ is **convex** and minimise $\lVert \hat{f} - f \rVert$ (for some norm).

Comment: Over what space of functions are you minimizing?

Comment: No, it won't be. The answer will typically depend on the norm used, but certainly not in general, and not for the $p$-norms (over a compact interval) for example. However, if you're minimising $\hat{f}$ over all convex minorants of $f$, then that's a different story (depending on the norm).

Comment: Oh, I realised that $f^{**}$ cannot be the best approximation in general. Thx!

Comment: @littleO Oh, sorry for that. I add an additional condition of convexity to $\hat{f}$.